# Single bolt seat clamp slipping

Tags: saddle, seatpost

I've got a Kindshock Dropzone seatpost with a single bolt clamp.

[image]

Even if I screw the bolt in hard the saddle will always slide to the back.

Any way to prevent it? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Unclear:  Are the rails slipping, or is the rail clamp rolling in it's "saddle"?

Comment: The saddle moves to the back along the rails - clamp does not hold tight enough

Comment: Then either the clamp is designed for larger diameter rails, or there is something inside the clamp (possibly a bit of mold sprue that wasn't removed in the factory) that is preventing the clamp from closing completely.

Answer (score 6):

I have never had a problem getting single bolt tight enough to hold.

Most likely is seat rail diameter - 7mm is common road, 9mm common MTB but there are others. (refer [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_saddle)).

Is there something assembled wrong, a piece upside down?

Although seat post bolts need to be tight, what ever you do, don't be 'that' "gorilla with a spanner" - it is never the correct approach when assembling bicycles.

Comment: Using a small amount of carbon paste can also help prevent slipping, although if it's frequently happening I'd suggest the rails weren't sized correctly.

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason why most high end seatposts use the two bolt design.

You could use a torque wrench to tighten the bolt to spec (which is tighter than most people would use without one), and grease the bolt to allow more tension.

Answer (score 3):

I presume it's assembled right.

Make sure the bolt threads and shoulder are clean and greased.

Putting a layer of fiber grip (aka carbon prep aka Liquid Torque, etc) on whatever area is slipping may help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you could do is add a thin piece of rubber underneath the rail clamp before you tighten it down.

That should have the same effect as using a rubberband to help remove a stripped screw.

The rubber will fill between the cracks that have been worn down, previously causing your saddle to slide back.

It's worth a shot considering it will cost you nothing or next to nothing.

Comment: Rubber tends to degrade under pressure and age and so it's not ideal for a shim material in these types of load situations (it's fine for mounting lights, etc.).